# Unity - Как сделать время одних объектов независимо от других?

Tags: c#, unity3d, время

Я имею ряд проблем и прошу помочь мне их решить.

**1)** Дело в том, что мне нужно сделать slow motion в игре. Но интерфейс и камера (спектатор) должны работать по стандартному времени (Time.timScale = 1)

Но используя Time.timeScale вся игра погружается в slow motinon, в том числе камера, анимация кнопок т.д.

В камере использую Input.GetAxis, который тоже работает от времени в игре и из-за этого при остановке времени (Time.timeScale = 0) и камера прекращает двигаться.

**2)** Думаю использовать отдельный скрипт, который будет иметь переменную типа float, к которой присваивается значение Time.deltaTime * n (где n - во сколько раз ускорено). Но это будет очень муторно, ведь тогда ко всему нужно будет привязывать эту переменную (к анимациям, движению персонажей, rigidBody и т.д.).

Можно ли как то иначе это использовать? Чтобы к примеру в одном скрипте использовалось **только** время с запуска игры, а не игровое время.

**3)**

```
 Time.timeScale = speedTime;
        timeText();
```

Камера (управление её)

```
float Ver = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speedcam;
        float Hor = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speedcam;

        cameraStatus.position += (cameraStatus.forward + cameraStatus.right) * Hor
        + (cameraStatus.up) * Ver;
```

(Камера - ортографическая, поэтому к ней такое управление)

*Заранее спасибо тем, кто помог мне*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создай `UnityEvent<float>` для `LevelUpdate`, в скрипте уровня, а все элементы уровня цепляй слушателями к этому эвенту, который обновляется в скрипте уровня с нужной `Time.deltaTime*GameSpeed` и в элементпх уровня используй вместо `Update()`.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант гораздо легче, просто те объекты которые не должны менять свою динамику при изменении `timeScale`, используйте `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` вместо `Time.deltaTime`

Comment: Я понимаю, но мне к примеру нужно добавить управление камерой во время slow motion. 

`float Ver = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speedcam;` *Но* сам Input.GetAxis содержит `Time.deltaTime` и поэтому изменяется и он.